# Touch in monogame does not work on some screens

Tags: c#, monogame, touchscreen

I'm writting simulation in Monogame and I have problem with touch detect on some touch screens. I need support mouse and touch screens so I used `Mouse.GetState()` to detect when left button is pressed. It is works with mouse and with some touch screens but some touch screens doesn't work correct.

For example Elotouch screen doesn't work. When I touch them Monogame can't detect correct state (I expect `LeftButton.Pressed`). Tapping is sometimes detected after few attempts. This screen has driver with some preferences and touching is detected only with mouse simulation config (other configs doesn't work). Screen can alert all touches by sound and when I use this option sound is play correctly on every touch.

I tried use `TouchPanel.GetState()` too but collection is always empty.

I tested simulation with few screens and some screens works correct. Has someone problems like that? Any ideas?

P.S. Monogame in 3.6 version. Screen and graphic card installed and updated. Tested on several computers (Win8 and Win10).

Comment: Could you be more specific which screens worked correctly?

Comment: iiyama PROLITE T1931SAW-B1 works fine